# Finding source of cause in Anomaly detection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

We have an Anomaly detection model using Autoencoders, which takes in 13 parameters. We want to detect which parameter is causing this anomaly.

Till now, we are exploring on how to do this, but haven't come across anything. Can anyone suggest some algorithm(s) on how to do this?

Comment: any news on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

[SHAP values](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/7062-a-unified-approach-to-interpreting-model-predictions) are nice for this. The [shap](https://github.com/slundberg/sha) Python library supports scikit-learn IsolationForest [since October 2019](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/pull/784), so that would be the easiest method.

You should be able to use the [DeepExplainer](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#shap.DeepExplainer) in shap for an Autoencoder implemetned in Keras/Tensorflow. There is also the generic/black-box [KernelExplainer](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/README.md#model-agnostic-example-with-kernelexplainer-explains-any-function), that can be applied to any model.